# convert period in stata to NA in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset in stata and I want to take it to R, but there are some missing values in state and they are represented using a period. I want to get the data into R which I do by loading the foreign package and then I use read.table() function. How do I convert the periods in state which are genuinely missing to NA in R?

Comment: `read.table` is part of base. If that's what you're using, look at the `na.strings` argument. Do you mean `read.dta`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you first load the Foreign-Package for loading a .dta-File, correct?

```
library("foreign")
```

Then you would read in your Data by using:

```
myRFile <- read.dta(file="someStataFile.dta")
```

You are asking for a way that the missing operator from Stata, often denoted by a dot `.`, is converted to the missing operator in R, `NA`, also correct?
One thing to know here is, that Stata handles missing values "behind the scenes" in multiple ways. There are actually about 27 different missing operators in Stata, which are usually not distinguishable for the user. You do not need to know them for you problem though, because `read.dta()` handles them itself.
To learn how you can tackle a simple problem like this yourself in the future, you always need to check the help file for your function first:

```
help(read.dta)
```

Here you see, that the function handles the extensive missing-data types from Stata automatically and correctly.

If you want to have information about which type of missing operator was recognized, you can set the argument `missing.type=TRUE`, by using:

```
myRFile <- read.dta(file="someStataFile.dta", missing.type=TRUE)
```

Then, according to the help file, the following will happen:

> If missing.type is TRUE a separate list is created with the same
>   variable names as the loaded data. For string variables the list value
>   is NULL. For other variables the value is NA where the observation is
>   not missing and 0–26 when the observation is missing. This is attached
>   as the "missing" attribute of the returned value.